# Grouping problems using two CTEs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code is providing correct numbers- Grouping is giving me a problem and this maybe a fundamental code chose issue. Query is as:

```
With 
P as ( Select sum(r.qty) as proposed, rm.entity, id, 
quarter (case When status = open then quarter = 1 ELSE 3 END) AS QUARTER, 
year (case When status = open then year = 2017 ELSE 2016 END) AS YEAR,
FROM Db1
Group By proposed, quarter, id, entity, quarter, year)

A as ( Select sum(r.qty) as awarded, rm.entity, id, 
quarter (case When status = open then quarter = 2 ELSE 4 END), 
year(case When status = open then year = 2018 ELSE 2016 END) 
From DB1
Group By proposed, quarter, id, entity, quarter, year
)

SELECT * FROM P right join a on p.id = a.id
Group By proposed, quarter, id, entity, quarter, year
```

My returns are something like:

```
ID  p.Quarter p.Year  a.Quarter  a.Year  Proposed Awarded
1     null      null     1       2017    null      1
2      2        2018     3       2017    1         1
2      1        2018     4       2016    1         1
3     null      null     2       2018    null      2
```

I want:

```
ID  p.Quarter p.Year  a.Quarter  a.Year  Proposed Awarded
1     null      null     1       2017    null      1
2      2        2018     null    null    1         null
2      1        2018     null    null    1         null
2     null      null     3       2017    null      1
2     null      null     4       2017    null      null
3     null      null     2       2018    null      2
```

The problem is - If an ID has a proposed date, quantity, awarded date and quantity I want all of the years and quarters to be shown outside of the id grouping. So each awarded or proposed count will have it's own row. Otherwise the counts are coming in wrong.

I am pulling from two different databases and my Case statements are much more complex but adding that large amount of code seed irrelevant for this.

Comment: Do you traditionally leave `FROM` and `GROUP BY` clauses out of your code?  The sample looks incomplete.

Comment: Oh no - sorry I was typing an example up real quick and forgot those. I'll update- thanks for noticing!